# Setting Time To Live (TTL) from Java - sample requested

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

**EDIT:**
[This is basically what I want to do, only in Java](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.search.elasticsearch.user/5446)

Using ElasticSearch, we add documents to an index bypassing IndexRequest items to a BulkRequestBuilder.

I would like for the documents to be dropped from the index after some time has passed (time to live/ttl)

This can be done either by setting a default for the index, or on a per-document basis. **Either approach is fine by me**.

The code below is an attempt to do it per document. It does not work. I think it's because TTL is not enabled for the index. **Either show me what Java code I need to add to enable TTL so the code below works, or show me different code that enables TTL + sets default TTL value for the index in Java** I know [how to do it from the REST API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html#_enabled_2) but I need to do it from Java code, if at all possible.

```
    logger.debug("Indexing record ({}): {}", id, map);
    final IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(_indexName, _documentType, id);
    final long debug = indexRequest.ttl();
    if (_ttl > 0) {
        indexRequest.ttl(_ttl);
        System.out.println("Setting TTL to " + _ttl);
        System.out.println("IndexRequest now has ttl of " + indexRequest.ttl());
    }
    indexRequest.source(map);
    indexRequest.operationThreaded(false);
    bulkRequestBuilder.add(indexRequest);
}

// execute and block until done.
BulkResponse response;
try {
    response = bulkRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

Later I check in my unit test by polling this method, but the document count never goes down.

```
public long getDocumentCount() throws Exception {
    Client client = getClient();
    try {
        client.admin().indices().refresh(new RefreshRequest(INDEX_NAME)).actionGet();

        ActionFuture<CountResponse> response = client.count(new CountRequest(INDEX_NAME).types(DOCUMENT_TYPE));
        CountResponse countResponse = response.get();
        return countResponse.getCount();
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you would like to set the `_ttl` for your document via Java API? that's not the same as setting the `_ttl` for *the index*. Did you enable the `_ttl` field in your mapping?

Comment: Right now I think my challenge is to enable the _ttl field for the index. I can apparently set it for the document - that's what I am doing above, right? - but it does not get purged.

Comment: I have updated the question to make my issue more clear.

Comment: As I said you need to [enable](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html#_enabled_2) `_ttl` in your mapping, as it's disabled by default. After that you can add the `_ttl` field to your documents and they should get purged.

Comment: Yes. How do I do that from the Java API?

Comment: @javanna I KNOW that I have to enable the _ttl in the mapping. I DON'T know how to do it from the Java API. That is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a LONG day of googling and writing test programs, I came up with a working example of how to use ttl and basic index/object creation from the Java API. Frankly most of the examples in the docs are trivial, and some JavaDoc and end-to-end examples would go a LONG way to help those of us who are using the non-REST interfaces.

Ah well.

Code here: [Adding mapping to a type from Java - how do I do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071198/adding-mapping-to-a-type-from-java-how-do-i-do-it)