# Mappings are not getting updated in ElasticSearch using java code

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have tried updating my mappings in elastic Search using Java Code.
But to my dismay the mappings are not getting updated

Following is my code

```
String settingsAsJson =getJsonString("settingFile");
client.admin().indices().close(new        CloseIndexRequest(indexName)).actionGet().isAcknowledged();
boolean settingsAck =   client.admin().indices().prepareUpdateSettings().setSettings(settingsAsJson).setIndices(indexName).execute().actionGet().isAcknowledged();
System.out.println("Applied SETTINGS "+ settingsAck);
String mappingAsJson = getJsonString("mappingFile");
boolean mappingack = client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping().setIndices(indexName).setType(indexType).setSource(mappingAsJson).execute().actionGet().isAcknowledged();
System.out.println("Applied Mappings "+ mappingack);
client.admin().indices().open(new OpenIndexRequest(indexName));
client.admin().indices().prepareFlush(indexName);
```

Following is my mapping file

```
{
"profiles": {
 "dynamic" : "true",
 "_all": {
 "type": "string",
 "analyzer": "standard"
 },
 "properties": {
 "employee_id": {
 "type": "integer",
  "analyzer":"standard"
  }
}
}
}
```

Also note, only the dynamic property changes the rest all new updation on mappings dont get updated.
Is there any other way to update mappings using java code?

Comment: Might want to have a look here .. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071198/adding-mapping-to-a-type-from-java-how-do-i-do-it/29107586#29107586

Hope it helps!

Comment: Usually if the mappings to not update you get the reason as part of the response. I don't know the java api so don't know where that description might be.

Comment: No Shashi, I tried your code PutMappingRequest mappingRequest = new PutMappingRequest(indexName);
        mappingRequest = mappingRequest.ignoreConflicts(true).type(indexType).source(mappingAsJson);
        System.out.printf("ack from mapping= " +client.admin().indices().putMapping(mappingRequest).actionGet().isAcknowledged());
also, but it's it's not updating the fields in mapping. And Also the response i get is acknowledged= true from java api